# Function that maps all vectors to the origin?

Tags: functions, vectors

I need a function that will map any vector (and any point on that vector) in the cartesian plane to (0,0) using only addition and subtraction. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, $f(v)=v-v$.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks.